# Use And Or in one query

Tags: php, mysql

I want to use `and`, `or` one query in MySQL.

How do I do that?

I tried this query but it didn't give me the result I want. I did some search some one say put () also didn't work.

```
select * from tbl_staff where db_user='".$_SESSION['username']."' and 
db_status!='Done' and db_status!='Cancelled' or db_transfered='$name'
```

I try to use brackets `( )` for the `and` like I read in some answer here but also didn't work. This query give me also the done and cancelled status and that what I don't want.

the idea like this i have a table

```
username transfered status
00021    mhmd         done
00022    mhmd         Running
00021                 Running
```

the output will be
the last 2 rows only that mean the user 00021 name mhmd have 1 task and the second is transferred to him from the username 00022 should also appear to 00021 without the done one

Comment: What is the logic behind the `WHERE` clause?

Comment: select * from tbl_staff where (db_user='".$_SESSION['username']."' and 
db_status!='Done' and db_status!='Cancelled' )or (db_transfered='$name')

Comment: @Anant sorry it didn't work

Comment: Please explain your logic

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen i want to select all from tbl_staff  i want to have all have db_user=$_SESSION all have db_transfered=$name without one who have done or cancelled status

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you explained right now:-

```
Select * FROM tbl_staff WHERE db_status!='Done' AND db_status!='Cancelled' AND (db_user='".$_SESSION['username']."'  OR db_transfered='$name')
```

Comment: please check above i do some explain

Comment: @mhmd  glad to help you. :):):)

Answer (score 0):

I'm confused what you actually want, I think your query should be

```
select * from tbl_staff where 
         db_user='".$_SESSION['username']."' AND 
         (db_status!='Done' AND db_status!='Cancelled') 
         AND db_transfered='$name';
```

Comment: @rbr94 sorry it was an mistake !! :(

Comment: please check above i do some explain